# UITableView inside TableCell

Tags: iphone, ipad, uikit

do anyone have experience with UITableView inside a custom UITableViewCell ?

I had a try and the UITableView in the UITableViewCell looks like that can't respond to user inputs (i.e scrolling).

Before going any further I would like to know if I am wasting my time !

Does anyone have seen something like that around ? Any reference would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: This seems like it could make for a very confusing user interface. Could you elaborate on why you'd like to do this? I'm not sure you can, but if you provide some context, we might be able to find an alternative way to achieve your goals.

Comment: This is the scenario. 1) Master-Details relationship 2) First Table used to create an input form for Master. 3) I would use the second table to manage the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done this, but I discourage this. This could cause odd things to happen.

In a similar vein, Apple says not to use UIWebView inside of a UIScrollView. The reason is because a web view *is* a subclass of the scroll view. Nesting them can cause unexpected behaviors. Note that the table view is also a subclass of the scroll view. While Apple doesn't explicitly mention your case, I assume that it is the same idea.

If yo must, subclass UITableViewCell and see what happens. It's not that difficult. Make the cell implement the UITableViewDelegate protocol.

Comment: Is the main reservation here only w.r.t.  the undefined (or unintuitive) scrolling behaviour?  If the inner table view's height is set such that all of its rows are visible on screen at once (i.e. no scroll), are there any other problems to be taken into consideration?

Comment: Probably not. At this point, it's worth investigating collection views.

Comment: i have similar type  question  any help i posted https://stackoverflow.com/q/45626816/6028575

Answer (score 0):

Since the parent TableView responds to the vertical swipe gesture, your child TableView is not going to ever see it.    Where should the swipe gesture "go"?   It has to go one place or the other, so one of the TableViews will always not behave "correctly".   I do think that trying to put a TableView inside  a TableViewCell and getting it to work just like a root TableView is probably a waste of time.