# how to display nested array data inside uitableview properly with Multiple level of Sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sections

I have the following json data

```
{
   "Display_Selected List": 
       [
        {
          "product_name": "Product1",
          "items": 
           [
            {   
              "item_name": "SubItem1",
              "specifications": 
               [
                {
                  "list": [
                    {
                      "name": "Sp1"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Sp2"
                    }
                  ],
                  "specification_name": "Specification Group 1"
                },
                {
                  "list": [
                    {
                      "name": "Sp3"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Sp4"
                    }
                  ],
                  "specification_name": "Specification Group 2"

                }
              ]
            },
            {   
              "item_name": "Sub Item2",
              "specifications": 
               [
                {
                  "list": [
                    {
                      "name": "Sp2"
                    }
                  ],
                  "specification_name": "Specification Group 1"
                },
                {
                  "list": [
                    {
                      "name": "Sp3"
                    }
                  ],
                  "specification_name": "Specification Group 2"

                }
              ]
            }
          ]
         },
         {
         "product_name": "Product2",
          "items": 
           [
            {   
              "item_name": "Item1",
              "specifications": 
               [
                {
                  "list": [
                    {
                      "name": "Sp3"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Sp4"
                    }
                  ],
                  "specification_name": "Specification Group 2"

                }
              ]
            }
            ]
            }
          ]
}
```

As per the design requirement i have to diplay this whole data in single uitable view like follow 
I have created rough design as shown in below image

[image]

> I can achieve  this via `uitableview` inside `uitableviewcell` but as
>   per Apple recommendation Apple does not recommend table views to be
>   added as subviews of other scrollable objects

Now my question is how can i achieve following design by single uitableview and and also as per my json all the content are dynamic

Does anyone have seen something like this around ? Any reference would be helpful.

Comment: you can use headerview for products if item name is display every time then you can add also in header..for item & specification group you use this tutorial sapandiwakar.in/nested-sections-in-uitableview

Comment: no my product shoud be sectionHeader as there is multple product array show Product>Item>Specification>List

Comment: yes product & item display every time ?

Comment: but if item has no any specification then it  array like this Product>item-second item

Comment: as per tutorial there is Sports >Bat-and-ball>Baseball but I have 4 level

Comment: yes. you can add product in header

Comment: Use dynamic height uitableviewcell ,  like we use in some chatting applications

Comment: there is no issue with height

Comment: yes i have same problem yesterday in my app. I have solve the issue using this tutorial

Comment: first read this you got solution

Comment: if you can calculate your cell height according to number of specification_name and number of  list item inside each specification name you can add label in cell.content view accordingly

Comment: you problem is same like tutorial.you need to add producs1,2 .... in header then same code

Comment: Design custom cell with multiple label. no need to add table inside a tableCell

Comment: how can i predict the number of label displayed inside uitableview cell as it is dynamic and creating label programatically  creates overload

Comment: you can predict the number of labels by data set , but its true it would be jerky. so i think you need to add a single label and change whole text into formatted text and assign formatted text to formatted label or textview , formatted label is open source uilabel category.It would be less overhead than adding labels programmatically

Comment: no actually i have drawn rough design my actual design is different for that i have to create customCell class for each section and row i post the code for differentiate array So formatting text is not working in my case

Comment: [Did you know this](https://github.com/IMcD23/IMTreeView) check that.

Comment: Check my answer if you are looking for a swift version https://stackoverflow.com/a/53282410/9497657

Answer (score 2):

If you don't wish to use `tableView` inside `tableViewCell`, you could possible go by the following approach.

- Create 3 different cells first one for showing item name, second one for showing the Specification group name and the third one for showing the specification items (eg: Sp1,Sp2,..)
- `numberOfRowsInSection` will have the correct count to show data using the above created cells. So numberOfRows should return the total count like rowsInSection = 
  count of items + count of specifications in each items + count of list in each specifications for each item
- Change your data source accordingly and make condition check so that you will display the item Name cell first then followed by the cell for Specification group name then display specification items inside each specification then show the next item name and so on.

I hope this approach will help you achieve the result.

It will be easy if you could use `tableView` inside the `tableViewCell`, in many Applications I have used this approach and I haven't faced any Apple review problem. If you are using `tableView` inside `tableViewCell` it would be better to disable scrolling and bounces property.

Comment: Apple does not recommend table views to be added as subviews of other scrollable objects that's why i am not using tableview cell as per your answer which is better tableview inside tableviewcell or creating 3 different cell, (in the terms of speed)

Comment: In terms of speed I guess using 3 different cells will be better. But managing the datasource can be a challenge

Comment: Thanks, I hope you would achieve the expected result with this approach. Good luck :)